# Unable to rename output files

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Our DataFlow job that reads two text files from GS folders, transforms them, and merges them before writing them to a BigQuery dataset is failing before the merge step with:

`Unable to rename output files from gs://xxx to gs://xxxx`

It would seem that the temp files are being deleted before the merge can start?

Comment: Would you be able to share your pipeline code?

Comment: What version of the Dataflow SDK are you using? Do the GCS buckets you are writing to have any kind of TTL on them? Is there a job ID available that we could look at for more details?

Comment: Pipeline:
   ` collection1 =  load_all_from_tsv(path1)
    collection2 =  load_all_from_tsv(path2)
    ((collection1, collection2)
        | 'Flaten both' >> beam.Flatten()
        | 'Format rows' >> beam.FlatMap(ourFormattingFunction)
        | 'Writing to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
               beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                   'project.outputdataset',
                   schema=schema,
                   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
               ))
    )`

Comment: It happened using the dataflow SDK v0.6 but I just upgraded to the latest (2.0.0). Beam is also (2.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

Issue found!
One of the two of the FlatMap functions was failing because of badly formatted data. Hint for anyone else that gets a similar issue: debug all map/pardo/etc functions with DirectRunner first!